# How do I use Visual Studio 2019 to remotely debug a .NetCore application on a Hyper-V Linux VM?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, ubuntu-20.04

I am attempting to remotely debug a .NetCore application in Ubuntu Linux from Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 10. I can see the remote ipaddress (ping thru command line). I can RDT to the ipaddress. I can successfully transfer files to it via WinSCP.

I created a simple .NetCore "HelloWorld" app and copied onto the Linux VM.
I used the following commands to build and publish:

```
dotnet build -r linux-x64 
dotnet publish --self-contained -r linux-x64
```

I ran the following command on the Linux VM to ensure that ssh is functional:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server unzip curl
```

The app is running on Linux.
**From VS I try to attach to the process:**

[image: VS Attach To Process]

**I get prompted for logon:**

[image: Log on to remote connection]

**I get the following error:**

[image: Error Message]

Is there a step I'm missing somewhere?
Is there a configuration/permissions issue I am unaware of?

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d79dd68-6131-4c41-8af6-453600c3e19a/vs2013-cannot-attach-to-chromeexe?forum=vsdebug  You might try experimenting with the different values in the "Attach to" dropdown

Comment: Do you have `vsdbg` installed on Linux? And you also need a launch configuration file according to [Debugging of .NET Core on Linux OSX](https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio) guide

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - link is bad. Asking for GitHub Authentication. Do I need vsdbg, even though I'm actually running VS on Windows10 box and attempting to remote debug?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has documented debugging a Linux target from a Windows development machine at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2022

Unfortunately, using that method, you will need to manually deploy and manually attach the debugger.  If you'd like Microsoft to change that, then it would be wise to upvote this issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Convenient-way-to-add-a-remote-debug-con/917516

A 3rd party developer has created a Visual Studio extension that provides this missing feature to Visual Studio.  It can be downloaded from https://github.com/radutomy/VSRemoteDebugger

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem initially because I didn't enter the connection target in the first screen.
After having entered the correct target myusername@192.168.178.95 in the first screen the second screen did not show up any longer and I got the expected list of processes